# How do I take full control of read only status for any file or folder on a Windows 8 machine

Tags: windows, windows-8, permissions, filesystems, read-only

I've just got a windows 8 machine and it seems to suffer from the same permissions bug as windows 7 whereby a folder is set to read only, seemingly arbitrarily, and it's impossible to unset. I've tried various tweaks in the security tab settings and also the way I used to do it before this bug was introduced, i.e. uncheck and click apply.

I am signed in as the admin user (the only user on the system at this stage) and the install is pretty fresh as I only bought the laptop a couple of days ago.

**Is there some conclusive way of taking complete control over any file or folder in a windows 8 system?**

Answer (score 2):

Source [Take Ownership of a File, Folder, Drive, or Registry Key in Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2808-take-ownership-file-folder-drive-registry-key-windows-8-a.html):

**Warning**: DO NOT take ownership of the Windows 8 C: drive.

Doing so, could result in Windows 8 becoming very unstable.

**Take Ownership of an Object using TAKEOWN Command**

This command will take ownership of the folder or drive, and all files and subfolders in the folder or drive.

Open an [elevated command prompt](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2754-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-8-a.html).

To grant ownership to currently logged on user:

```
takeown /F "full path of folder or drive" /R /D Y
```

To grant ownership to administrators group:

```
takeown /F "full path of folder or drive" /A /R /D Y
```

Examples:

```
takeown /F "F:" /A /R /D Y
takeown /F "F:\Folder" /A /R /D Y
```

**To Take Ownership of Only a Folder or Drive using ICALCS Command**

Open an [elevated command prompt](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2754-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-8-a.html).

To set any user as owner:

```
icacls "full path of folder or drive" /setowner "user name" /C
```

To set administrators group as owner:

```
icacls "full path of folder or drive" /setowner "Administrators" /C
```

Example:

```
icacls "C:\Windows\Folder" /setowner "Administrators" /C
```

**To Take Ownership of a Folder or Drive and All Contents using ICALCS Command**

Open an [elevated command prompt](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2754-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-8-a.html).

To set any user as owner:

```
icacls "full path of folder or drive" /setowner "user name" /T /C
```

To set administrators group as owner:

```
icacls "full path of folder or drive" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C
```

Example:

```
icacls "C:\Windows\Folder" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C
```